# Convert json string into array

Tags: json

I unable to decode following json string into array.Please help.

a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:14:"Name of lender";s:21:"AA Financial Services";s:14:"Account number";s:10:"1234567890";}i:1;a:2:{s:14:"Name of lender";s:11:"Barclaycard";s:14:"Account number";s:10:"1234567890";}}

Comment: That's not JSON. It looks like a PHP serialised object (demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e1e732fc3b6c0bd6e5b4ebaf8a410a0afb4eb51). Please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php . And please also make sure you fully understand JSON syntax - if you did, it would be instantly obvious that this string isn't valid JSON, even if you didn't know what else it was.

Comment: So,how to read data from this object?.Please help me

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to?? Did look at the demo I gave?? I don't think you've had time yet...they explain everything you need. Please use the information people give you before asking for more help! I didn't post those links so that you could ignore them.

Comment: Thank you so much.My issue resolved now.